# Dictionary that maps ASCII keys to their corresponding values

Tags: python, dictionary, ascii, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to get `chr()` output from 65 to 90:

I want to get a dictionary that looks like this:

`{65: 'A', 66: 'B', ..... 90: 'Z'}`

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple `dict` comprehension

```
>>> {x: chr(x) for x in range(65, 91)}
{65: 'A', 66: 'B', 67: 'C', 68: 'D', 69: 'E', 70: 'F', 71: 'G', 72: 'H', 73: 'I', 74: 'J', 75: 'K', 76: 'L', 77: 'M', 78: 'N', 79: 'O', 80: 'P', 81: 'Q', 82: 'R', 83: 'S', 84: 'T', 85: 'U', 86: 'V', 87: 'W', 88: 'X', 89: 'Y', 90: 'Z'}
```